# How to get local issuer certificate on wsl2?

Tags: python, ssl

I'm now stucking with SSL when using Windows SubSystem WSL2 Ubuntu. Specifically, I need to read table on website, and I'm using `pandas.read_html(url)`. However, It warns me the Error like this

```
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)
```

How can I solve this problem? What is the root of it?

Comment: What was the issue? did you solve it?